# Prove that if $V$ and $W$ are orthogonal subspaces, then $V \cap W=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I am having issues with this problem:

If $V$ and $W$ are orthogonal subspaces then
prove that  $V \cap W=\{0\}$

I have tried many methods and techniques but I keep getting it wrong.

Comment: Have you tried proof by contradiction?

Comment: No I have not, could you explain it?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $v \in V \cap W$. Then $v \bot v$, or $\langle v , v \rangle = \|v\|^2 = 0$ and so $v = 0$.

Comment: Don't what have to be two different vectors?